# How do we group using aggregate for different match cases?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a user data

```
   users = [{
      name : 'z',
      movie : 'yes',
      finance : 'no'
    },
{ 
    name : 'zee',
    movie : 'no',
    finance : 'yes'},
{
    name : 'zoo',
    movie : 'yes'
    }]
```

I need to group them like

```
{
totalUsers : 3,
movieWatch : 2,
financeUsed : 1,
financeNotDone : 1 }
```

I tried understanding aggregate but found the we can do it for one match or like i haven't understood properly please help me out

I'm new to aggregate concepts.

Comment: [How about a little search?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baggregation-framework%5D+%24sum+%24cond+%24+group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can try it

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id: null,
        totalUsers: {$sum:1},
        movieWatch: {$sum: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$movie", 'yes' ] }, 1, 0 ]}},
        financeUsed : {$sum: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$finance", 'yes' ] }, 1, 0 ]}},
        financeNotDone  : {$sum: {$cond: [ { $eq: [ "$finance", 'no' ] }, 1, 0 ]}}
        }}
]);
```